Can you split all connected bones and change them all to a ''keep offset'' parent automatically in a rig?
Like I do here, but automatically.


you can select all the bones in Edit mode and Alt P > Clear Parent

Considering all of the bones are parented and connected:
Select bones you need in the Edit mode, go the Bone tab, holding Alt uncheck "Connected".
P.S. Alt applies the action to all selected objects, e.g. to change materials on multiple objects.

Select all the bones and AltP > Disconnect Bone:


Won't this just unparent the bones? You still need to parent with "keep offset" manually, as I know

My bad, Alt P > Disconnect Bone is correct I guess?

Just checked, it works too.
